# Pushing OData filters down through layers

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-web-api, odata

I have a working project with the following layers:

- DataAccess - The project hits multiple DBs and web services. This layer defines the interfaces to each of them. It exposes the native types for each source (EF types for DBs, SOAP-defined types for web services, etc.). Let's say it exposes an EFProject and SoapProject.
- Repository - This layer stiches results from the various sources to form a single entity, and exposes it. Let's call this ModelProject
- Service - Adds REST attributes to to the entity (action links, etc.). This exposes a ProjectDTO.
- WebApi - The controller spits out the ProjectDTO directly.

I'm trying to implement OData, specifically to page the results of very large queries. I've read a lot of examples, but they all seem to expose the source objects directly, and then map them to the final DTOs in the controller.

I would like to somehow push the ODataQueryOptions down to the Repository. This would allow me to keep the existing structure, and pass the query logic down to SQL. I understand that, because the ODataQueryOptions reference the ProjectDTO type, they can't be applied until an object of that type is available. Is there a way to "translate" the ODataQueryOptions from one type to another? Is there another way of doing this that I'm not aware of?

Answer (score 0):

It is able to change the ODataQueryOptions, and such actions in a controller are for you to handle the options yourself:

1. public IQueryable Get(ODataQueryOptions queryOptions)
2. public IQueryable Get(int key, ODataQueryOptions queryOptions)

Here is a sample about this:
https://aspnet.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#Samples/WebApi/OData/v4/ODataQueryableSample/Controllers/OrdersController.cs .

For your reference, the source code of ODataQueryOptions is: https://aspnetwebstack.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#src/System.Web.OData/OData/Query/ODataQueryOptions.cs

Comment: Thanks, Tan. The problem is that the ODataQueryOptions object is designed to be applied on a collection of objects that the WebApi layer knows about (ProjectDTO in my question). I need to apply the query at the repository layer so that EF interprets it as something it can run against the database, not the final collection of objects.

Comment: The ODataQueryOptions is not only for a collection but also for a single object( such as $select).  By implementing these 2 type of methods, you can translate the options to other inside the method body. For example translate ODataQueryOptions.SelectExpandQueryOption into what the EF can consume, then just consume it.

Comment: That's what I'm working on now. I'm effectively writing my own version of ODataQueryOptions to get the query down to the appropriate layer. My question was more about whether there was anything out there that did this translation, or if there was another way of doing it.

Comment: I don't know other ways.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a way to "translate" the ODataQueryOptions from one type to another? Is there another way of doing this that I'm not aware of?

There is a way to actually translate the `IQueryable<DomainModel>` to `IQueryable<DtoModel>`.

I've done something similar in the past by leveraging [AutoMapper's projection functionality](http://docs.automapper.org/en/stable/Queryable-Extensions.html). By calling the `Project<TSource>`/`To<TTarget>` methods, you can change an `IQueryable` that points to your domain models to another `IQueryable` that targets the Dto models, **without actually executing it**.

This means that you can now perform any OData operations on the DTO level and they will transfer through projection to the DAL layer into EntityFramework and SQL. In a scenario like this, there shouldn't be any need to manually handle the query logic so you can just use `[EnableQuery]` on the API route and let OData do its thing on the resulting `IQueryable<DtoModel>`.

I used this very successfully in one of the projects I worked on: as long as you rely just on AutoMapper projection to convert the types, it should work fine.

Granted, you can't do a lot of fancy mapping that way. The project methods will not be able to apply all kinds of mappings that you create, so I recommend checking the documentation on that front.

You also have to keep in mind that the original `IQueryable` needs to be exposed outside of the repository layer for this to work properly, otherwise the query will be executed too early. Some people will find that a boundary violation and will advocate for materializing the query inside the repository layer, but I don't have an issue with that particular aspect.